# Update Query from one document to another table Row wise

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
[@FARMCOST]      OIGE          IGE1
-----------      ------        -----------
u_farmname       Docnum        ItemName
u_blockcode      DOCentry      qty
u_cost           U_FarmName    Price
                               LineTotal
                               U_FarmName
                               U_blockcode
                               DOCentry
```

I have a query

```
UPDATE [dbo].[@FARMCOST]
SET u_cost = u_cost + (
        SELECT b.LineTotal
        FROM OIGE a
        INNER JOIN IGE1 b ON a.DOCentry = b.docentry
        )
WHERE u_farmname = (
        SELECT a.U_FarmName
        FROM OIGE a
        INNER JOIN IGE1 b ON a.DOCentry = b.docentry
        )
    AND U_BlockCode = (
        SELECT a.U_BlockCode
        FROM IGE1 a
        INNER JOIN IGE1 b ON a.DOCentry = b.docentry
        WHERE
        GROUP BY a.U_BlockCode
        )
```

I have two document one is Block Cost ;i.e. [dbo].[@FARMCOST] @ and the 2nd is Issue Doc i.e. OIGE Master Table and IGE1 child table .

now i want to update the Block Cost Table against the enter code hereselected Blocks i.e IGE1.U_BlockCode .
the above query is working fine it is updating for one Row i.e one item but when i select multiple rows with diffrent blocks i am getting error.

any Help/Idea will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Can you describe your tables and columns please?  [@FARMCOST] is a funny name for a persistant table - normally you'd avoid starting with an @ symbol to avoid confusing it with a table variable...

Comment: Hi Jamees, in table Blockcost table  i have 3 fields called BlockCode,Farm Name and the cost , 1 farm can have multiple blocks . and the other tables are OIGE and IGE1 , now i want to update the fields Cost in FarmCost Table from IGE1 that has also the same fields called BlockCode and Farm Name , the above query is working only for one row , but when i select multiple rows in IGE1 with diffrent blocks but same farm query does not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general syntax for updating a batch of entries in one table taking data from other tables is

```
UPDATE dst
SET col = whatever
FROM dst
JOIN src ON dst.columnName = src.columnName
```

of course you can use table aliases here.

So your update query should look something like:

```
UPDATE fc 
SET u_cost = u_cost + grp.LineTotalSum
FROM [dbo].[@FARMCOST] AS fc
JOIN (
    SELECT OIGE.U_FarmName, IGE1.U_blockCode, SUM(IGE1.LineTotal) AS LineTotalSum
    FROM OIGE 
        JOIN IGE1 ON OIGE.U_FarmName = IGE1.U_FarmName
    GROUP BY OIGE.U_FarmName, IGE1.U_blockCode
) as grp ON fc.u_FarmName = grp.U_FarmName AND fc.u_blockcode = grp.U_blockcode
```

NB - I'm making a best estimate based on your question. If there are any column names wrong, or I've misinterpreted the foreign keys then please make them more clear in your question.

Comment: Hi James, i am working on a application called SAP B1 that has own system tables and we have a option to create user defined tables , so all user defined tables start with @ sign , here @farmcost is a UDT and OIGE, IGE1 are system tables called master and child respectively.

Comment: Can you update your question with the column names from these tables please

Comment: ok my columns names are FC.farmname ,FC.blockcode,FC.Cost from table FC and OIGE.Docnum from OIGE Table and IGE1.ItemName,IGE1.qty,IGE1.Price ,IGE1.LineTotal,IGE1.FarmName,IGE1.blockcode from IGE1 table.  BlockCode and Farm Name fields are common feilds in FC  and IGE1 table.

Comment: I edited your question, and added that information for you - but its clearly not complete, as you are missing things like `FC.u_cost` which you reference in your query. Please update your question to include all the relevant columns that you are using as part of your query or updating.

Comment: Hi James , I am new to this community , sorry if i did not mentioned my fields clearly. let me try once more fc.u_cost and fc.cost , fc.farmname and fc.u_farmname are the same fields, here "u_" is the prefix for user defined fields.

Comment: ok @Manish - I've edited your question again. If I have any fields wrong in your tables then please correct them yourself. I've also updated my answer - see if that works for you. For future reference you need to be upfront with your table schema when asking a question like this - its very difficult to answer when you dont have the information

Comment: ok James i will correct that no issue and thanks a lot for helping.